# Configure vim word boundary highlight for Bash function names

Tags: bash, vim

In vim, when I have a Bash function that ends with a Bash keyword, my vim highlighting starts highlighting it and assumes a new scope (if applicable):

```
values-for() {
  ...
}

       ^yellow "for" highlight
^syntax error highlight
```

But when I rename the "for" word to "for1" then those undesired highlights disappear.

How do I tell vim to ignore keywords like "for" when it is used as part of a function name?

Answer (score 1):

- I cannot reproduce this with the `$VIMRUNTIME/syntax/sh.vim` script (that ships with Vim 8.0.1358), version 172 from Oct 02, 2017 (assuming a proper `#!/bin/bash` shebang, so that the syntax detects the Bash dialect).
- On the maintainer's web site, there's an even [newer update](http://www.drchip.org/astronaut/vim/index.html#SYNTAX_SH) (version 174).
- If you can still reproduce the problem with that version, please contact DrChip via email and report this bug.
- Just to be clear, this is something that you cannot fix "in Vim"; it's a bug in the syntax definition itself, so that must be changed.

Answer (score 0):

[Word boundaries](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/pattern.html#/%5C%3C) are `\<` and `\>`. So use `\<for\>`.